# OpenCv Project Guidance for tracking humans

Tags: python, windows, opencv, project, vision

I am currently making a program with OpenCv that detects 2 colours. My next step is to leave a "translucent" path of where both these colours have moved. The idea is that every time they cross over their trail it will get a shade darker.

Here is my current code:

```
# required libraries
import cv2
import numpy as np

# main function


def main():

    # returns vid from camera -- cameras are indexed(0 is the front camera, 1 is rear)
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    # cap is opened if pc is receiving cam data
    if cap.isOpened():
        ret, frame = cap.read()

    else:
        ret = False

    while ret:
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        # setting color range
        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        # BLUE color range
        blue_low = np.array([100, 50, 50])
        blue_high = np.array([140, 255, 255])
        # GREEN color range
        green_low = np.array([40, 40, 40])
        green_high = np.array(([80, 255, 255]))

        # creating masks
        blue_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, blue_low, blue_high)
        green_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, green_low, green_high)

        # combination of masks
        blue_green_mask = cv2.bitwise_xor(blue_mask, green_mask)
        blue_green_mask_colored = cv2.bitwise_and(blue_mask, green_mask, mask=blue_green_mask)

        # create the masked version (shows the background black and the specified color the color coming through cam)
        output = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=blue_green_mask)

        # create/open windows
        cv2.imshow("image mask", blue_green_mask)
        cv2.imshow("orig webcam feed", frame)
        cv2.imshow("color tracking", output)

        # if q is pressed the project breaks
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    # once broken the program will run remaining instructions (closing windows and stopping cam)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    cap.release


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

My question now is how would I add the trail of where both colours have gone? I have also read that I will run into a problem when the trail is implemented as insignificant objects may be detected as one of the colours and leave an unwanted trail.. meaning I will need to find a way to only trail the largest object of the specified colours.

**EDIT:**
For further clarification:
I am using 2 black highlighters (one with a blue cap and one with a green cap).
With regards to the trail I am referring to something similar to this:..
[trail clarification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUZLQ.png)

This guy did an okay job at explaining it but I was still very confused which is why I came to stack overflow for help.

with the trails; I would like for them to be 'translucent' and not solid like in the picture above. therefore if the object crosses over its path again that section of the path will become a shade darker.

hope this helped:)

Comment: could you add some pictures that illustrate what objects and trails you're talking about?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Hi, I just added more detail. Hope you can help!

Comment: generally, "transparency" effects are achieved with multiplication and addition. you would keep an "overlay" picture and only paint the tracks in there, then composite that with transparency onto whatever is the background. if you need a track to be able to self-intersect and that intersection to become denser, you will need another buffer/overlay. the second (uppermost) overlay gets a single line/stroke. that is then composited into the first overlay, to have a chance for self-intersections to become denser. *that* you composite onto the background itself with however much transparency.